# Finding the mirror of coordinates through a midpoint

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the reflection of a point after passing through a midpoint, ie. basically the opposite of the point. My midpoint (mid_x, mid_y) is (5, 5). Is there a simple function to do this?

my df:

```
    x1, y1, mid_x, mid_y
0   7   3    5      5
1   4   8    5      5
2   1   6    5      5
```

wanted result:

```
    x1, y1, mid_x, mid_y  new_x1  new_y1
0   7   3    5      5       3      7
1   4   8    5      5       6      2
2   1   6    5      5       9      4
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the columns for `new_x1` and `new_y1` by:

```
df['new_x1']=2*df['mid_x']-df['x1']
```

Similarly for df['new_y1']

```
df['new_y1']=2*df['mid_y']-df['y1']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
df['new_x1'] = 2*df['mid_x'] - df['x1']
df['new_y1'] = 2*df['mid_y'] - df['y1']
df
Out[1]: 
   x1  y1  mid_x  mid_y  new_x1  new_y1
0   7   3      5      5       3       7
1   4   8      5      5       6       2
2   1   6      5      5       9       4
```